# jQuery ui sortable how to change prev/next item position in table structure

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery ui sortable to sort all td elements along with the parent tr element which has specific class. Parent tr element sorting is working fine. But while sorting the td elements the previous td element is moved next to the dropped item.

How can I change position of the previous td element to not move into the next position?

In short how can I force positions to swap between td elements when sorting?

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnws4otv/8/">https://jsfiddle.net/cnws4otv/8/)

Html code

```
<table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%" class="ui-sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="4%">Remove Row</th>
      <th width="20%">Name</th>
      <th width="40%">PDF</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="main_row main_row_static indexid_0" data-mainindex="0" data-totalpdfurlcount="5">
      <td>
        <a class="button remove-row" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" name="repeatable_fields[0][name]" value="First">
      </td>
      <td class="pdf_data" data-count_pdf="0">
        <input type="text" id="count_pdf_input-0" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1" name="repeatable_fields[0][url][]" value="1">
        <input class="upload_image_button" data-count_pdf="0" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <a class="button add-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-plus"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_0">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[0][url][1]" value="1.1">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_0">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[0][url][2]" value="1.2">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <!--a class="button add-pdf" data-daynamic='true' href="#">+</a>-->
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_0">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[0][url][3]" value="1.3">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_0">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[0][url][4]" value="1.4">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <!--a class="button add-pdf" data-daynamic='true' href="#">+</a>-->
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>        

  <tbody>         
    <tr class="main_row main_row_static indexid_1" data-mainindex="1" data-totalpdfurlcount="6">
      <td>
        <a class="button remove-row" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" name="repeatable_fields[1][name]" value="Second">
      </td>
      <td class="pdf_data" data-count_pdf="1">
        <input type="text" id="count_pdf_input-1" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1" name="repeatable_fields[1][url][]" value="2">
        <input class="upload_image_button" data-count_pdf="1" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <a class="button add-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-plus"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[1][url][1]" value="2.1">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <!--a class="button add-pdf" data-daynamic='true' href="#">+</a>-->
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[1][url][2]" value="2.3">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <!--a class="button add-pdf" data-daynamic='true' href="#">+</a>-->
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[1][url][3]" value="2.4">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <!--a class="button add-pdf" data-daynamic='true' href="#">+</a>-->
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[1][url][4]" value="2.5">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <!--a class="button add-pdf" data-daynamic='true' href="#">+</a>-->
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sub_pdf_files indexid_1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="pdf_data_inner">
        <input type="text" class="widefat widefatpdfs upload_image1 removepdf" name="repeatable_fields[1][url][5]" value="2.6">
        <input class="upload_image_button removepdf" data-daynamicadded="true" type="button" value="Select PDF">
        <!--a class="button add-pdf" data-daynamic='true' href="#">+</a>-->
        <a class="button remove-pdf" href="javascript:void(0)">
          <span class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

js code

```
$("#repeatable-fieldset-one").sortable({
  items: "tbody",
  handle: ".main_row_static"
});


$("tbody").sortable({
  items: "tr > td:last-child",
  update: function(event, ui){
    },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if ($(ui.item).parent('.main_row').length > 0) {
        var get_pdf_count = $(ui.item).parent('.main_row').attr('data-mainindex');
         $(ui.item).switchClass('pdf_data_inner', 'pdf_data');
       $(ui.item).attr("data-count_pdf", get_pdf_count);
    } else {
             $(ui.item).switchClass('pdf_data', 'pdf_data_inner');
         $(ui.item).removeAttr("data-count_pdf");
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort the row as a whole, otherwise the td that you are sorting will be placed in the same row as another td.

So, change `items: "tr > td:last-child"` to `items: "tr:not(.main_row)`.

If you want to sort those items into another tbody, say you want to put `2.1` before `1.1`, you would use the option `connectWith: 'tbody'`.

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Souleste/kc09fs8u/10/)